# Query for does not contain

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet that queries three others in the same document and selects a bunch of rows where the column G contains `no`. Ideally I would prefer it be a query that does not contain the word `yes` or `Yes`. I have tried using all of the following mechanisms:

- where not (G contains 'yes')
- where not (G contains 'es')
- where not (G matches '[yY]es')
- where G contains 'no'

and no matter which one I pick I run into one of two issues:

Issue number 1 is that part of the query fails because only one of the values is present. Ie there is a `Yes` but not a `yes`, which results in the output of `#VALUE`. This is problematic because I am trying to allow for both scenarios since I cannot control what the end user of this will input into the sheet.

or Issue number 2 which is far worse. When I specifically say select all where G contains `no` one of the rows that displays contains a `yes`. Note that this also occurs with some of the other mechanisms as well but I would think specifically saying `no` should prevent this and does not.

The full query I am using is:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(Sheet1!A2:I500, "Select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I where G contains 'no'");(QUERY(Sheet2!A2:I500, "Select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I where G contains 'no'"));(QUERY(Sheet3!A2:I500, "Select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I where G contains 'no'"))})`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I just tried changing it to `G = 'no'`  instead and got the same results. Yes is still showing up as a result. 0.o

Comment: sample data that causes a problem:

A) 1800---- body shop  
B) part number   
C) BMP cov etc.  
D) Ed  
E)  
F)     
G) Yes    

sorry about the formatting. But that one will show up in the query even though G is clearly Yes when it should be no

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bsM1VLx-KkDe165CP_owjcfiY2HT-rzZ_9KjwRXIpF8/edit?usp=sharing

it looks like its pulling 2 results and jamming them into one row.
then correctly pulling one result per row for each other result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the query range. It starts a Row2 which contains data rather than labels. By default the first row of a query is treated as heading for the output (so selection criteria are not applied to it). Hopefully a fix is just to adjust the query to exclude headings. Please try:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:I500,"Select * where G = 'no'", 0)
```

Comment: That was it. You are the best. ^_^

Answer (score 15):

The specific issue here was the query range. But the actual answer to the question (how do I query not like / not contain) is different.

I couldn't find this in the [query reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where) but the answer is to put not straight after the where:

```
"Select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I where not G contains 'yes'"
```

To further improve, you should lower(G) to make it exclude 'Yes' and 'yes'